# Unable to test nested Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller

How do I manage to test **Task::HoursController**?
The requests from my rspec test hits **HoursController**, not **Task::HoursController**

**The route**

`# POST /tasks/:task_id/hours(.:format)  tasks/hours#create`

**The test**

```
describe Tasks::HoursController, :type => :controller do

  it "assigns all hours as @hours" do
      hour = Hour.create! valid_attributes
      get  :index, { task_id:  @task.id }, valid_session
      assigns(:hours).should eq([hour])
  end
end
```

**The log output**

```
Processing by HoursController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"task_id"=>"207"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was hard for you guys to see, as I didn't post the code to my controller.

The fix was this:

```
-class Tasks::HoursSpentController < ApplicationController
+module Tasks
+  class HoursSpentsController < ApplicationController
```

And the suggestion @vince-v posted.
Thanks Vince. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to remove the Tasks namespace (also note that in your description you use singular and in the code plural)

and put the describe block in a module with task namespace.

```
module Tasks
  describe HoursController do
    it "assigns all hours as @hours" do
        hour = Hour.create! valid_attributes
        get  :index, { task_id:  @task.id }, valid_session
        assigns(:hours).should eq([hour])
    end
  end
end
```